# Detect if admin prefix is true from Model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have made a custom afterFind function in a model, but I just want it to execute it if NOT in admin mode.

```
public function afterFind($results) {
    if(Configure::read('Routing.admin')){
       return $results;
    }else{
       return $this->locale(&$results);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seems to work. I'm thinking this might not be possible. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

checking on the core Configure settings doesnt make sense to me.
besides the fact that that 'Routing.admin' is deprecated - its Prefix.admin.
it only stores the prefixes that cake uses.

If you really want to you can store the information in configure::read() in beforeFilter() of your AppController and read it from your model again.
But it would need to something that does not conflict with your settings.
So if you use `Prefix` you probably could use `Routing` again:

```
//beforeFilter - prior to any model find calls!
$isAdmin = !empty($this->params['admin']);
Configure::write('Routing.admin', $isAdmin);
```

the other option you always have is to pass the information on to the model.

Comment: yeah, I actually realized that reading 'Routing.admin' wouldn't make the trick, but it was actually for making me understand.

this solutions worked wonderfully well, I Just used $this->params['admin'] instead, it seemed to work better in my app.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`Router::getParam('prefix', true)` gives you current request prefix value.

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    return Router::getParam('prefix', true) == 'admin' ? $results : $this->locale(&$results);
}
```

Tested with Cake 2.4.